# $T$ is the scalar multiple of the identity operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Original question : Suppose that $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, is such that every non-zero vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

My proof: Since every non-zero arbitrary vector $v_j\in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$, we have $$Tv_j=\lambda_j v_j$$with $v_j\neq0$.

Suppose $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ is basis of $V$ (Clearly, there can't have zero vector) and suppose an arbitrary vector $v\in V$ with $v\neq 0.$ 
Then $$Tv=T(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)=a_1\lambda_1v_1+\cdots+a_n\lambda_nv_n$$ Since we know by theorem that if $a$ and $b$ are eigenvector of $T$, then $a+b$ is also eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the same eigenvalues. Thus we have $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n$. Therefore $$Tv=\lambda_1(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)=\lambda_1v.$$This means no matter what vector we put, we have the same eigenvalues for all eigenvectors. Therefore the eigenvalues is independent of the eigenvectors and we can conclude that $$Tv=\lambda_1 v=\lambda_1 Iv=(\lambda_1 I)v$$for which $T$ is a scalar multiple of identity operator.

Is my proof valid?

Comment: No this isn't valid.  If $a$ and $b$ are eigenvectors *corresponding to the same eigenvalue,* then $a+b$ is an eigenvector corresponding to that eigenvalue.  You're assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: @orole I don't follow this.  $v_1+v_3 \mapsto v_1$  What is the eigenvalue?

Comment: @nevergraduating The statement is true, but the proof does not work.

Comment: @saulspatz, what do you mean by assuming what I want to prove? I want to prove $T$ is scalar multiple of identity operator isn't ?

Comment: I meant that in the middle of the proof, you're trying to prove that all the basis vectors correspond to the  same eigenvalue, but the theorem you quote is only valid if you already know that they're associated with the same eigenvalue.  Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @saulspatz, That theorem generally means "If $u$, $v$ and $u+v$ are eigenvectors of $T$, then $u$ and $v$ must have the same eigenvalues." What's on my mind is $u+v$ must be an eigenvector in this question as every non-zero vector is an eigenvector. So this implies eigenvalues of $u$ and $v$ must be the same.

Comment: Oh I think I know what's going wrong. I wrote wrongly in my question "If $a$ and $b$ are eigenvector of T, then $a+b$ is also eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the same eigenvalues."

The true one should be "If $a$ and $b$ are eigenvector of $T$ and $a+b$ is also eigenvector of $T$, then they have the same corresponding eigenvalues." Sorry for the bad writing.

Comment: Okay.  We're on the same wavelength now.

Comment: Thanks for it !!

Comment: @Nothing What about some $a_i$ is zeor? Then, doesn't it affect your proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint. Let $e_1, e_2, ... e_n$ be a basis, $e_i \mapsto \lambda_i e_i, 1 \le i \le n.$  What can you say if $e_1 + e_2 \mapsto \lambda(e_1+e_2)?$

Comment: eigenvalues of $e_1,e_2$ and $e_1+e_2$ is $\lambda$

Comment: Right.  Now generalize it for any pair of basis vectors.  Doesn't that prove the theorem?

Comment: that's means the eigenvalue of $Tv=T(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)=a_1Tv_1+\cdots+a_nTv_n=a_1\lambda v_1+\cdots+\lambda v_n=\lambda v$ is $\lambda$ ?

Comment: Yes.  (There's a small mistake.  You wrote $\lambda v_n$ instead of $a_n \lambda v_n,$ but I'm sure that's just a typo.)