# The matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $B \in GL(d, \mathbb{R})$. Assume that $\{v_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is eigenvectors (not necessarily linearly independent eigenvectors) of $B$ and $\lambda_k$ is the corresponding eigenvalues of $B$. Assume that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_N\}$ from a basis of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ Is it true that  $B$ must be a scalar multiple of the identity transformation?

My proof:
for any $l>N$,  $v_l$ can be written as
$$v_l = c_1v_1 +\ldots + c_Nv_N.$$

Applying $B$ on both sides and using the fact that each $v_k$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$, we get $\lambda_lv_l = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N c_i\lambda_iv_i$. Substituting the above equation for $v_l$ into $\lambda_lv_l$ and equating coefficients gives $\lambda_l = \lambda_1 = \ldots =\lambda_N$. This implies what I want.

I am a bit worried as some $c_i$ can be zero, and that makes some problems.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not true, you only have $B$ diagonalizable, i.e. there exists $P$ invertible such that $P B P^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix. For example the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Is not a multiple of the identity.

I don't know why you think that $ \forall l, \lambda_l v_l = \sum \lambda_i c_i v_i \implies  \forall i,j, \, \lambda_i = \lambda_j$, it only gives you $c_{i} \in \{0,1\}$ and in fact $c_i = \delta_l^I$.

Plus $N = d$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628330/t-is-the-scalar-multiple-of-the-identity-operator?rq=1 Here proves that I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, is it now ok?

Comment: No this does not prove what you wanted look more closely to both statements.

Comment: Yes! It is! Could you please let me know the difference between them?

Comment: You suppressed the condition "all non zero vectors are eigenvectors" which is indeed equivalent to "L is an homotetia"

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please wait 2 min? I am writing a long comment.

Comment: What's essential in the other valid statement is the stability by addition.

Comment: As I wrote, Let $\{v_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be all non-zero eigenvectors of $B$. Let $W_k:=\text{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k}\}$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}.$ Assume that $W_d = \mathbb{R}^d.$ Can I get a similar statement? If not, what mild condition helps me to get it?

Comment: what do you mean by the stability by addition?

Comment: First of all, the set of Eigenvectors is countable iff you don't have any eigenvectors (it is not a vector space), I wrote the condition, maybe rework the other proof, you are blinded by something but I don't know what. I answered you: you can't. Stability by addition means that if $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors, so is $v + w$

Comment: Sorry for keep asking! Assume that my $W_d$ is equal to $V$ of that question. Every non-zero vector is an eigenvector of $B$. You also mentioned that  I suppressed the condition "all non zero vectors are eigenvectors", but I have this condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146828/discussion-between-jules-besson-and-adam).